# Unhandled Exception. Could not file or assembly "System Memory)

Tags: c#, winforms

After I included some .cs files from another project in my application when I publish my app and run it I get the following error.

[image]

My application is a windows form and the files I included are some kind of file parser in order to process a certain file type.

I have tried many times to rebuild and reload the project but the result is still the same. The target framework is .NET 4.8.

Does anybody has any idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because most probably, the code you inserted requires the presence of that dependency.
However, System.Memory is not part of the default framework, it's current version is 4.5.4 and it can be found on nuget.

If you use Visual Studio, you can conveniently add it to your Solution by using the Nuget Package Manager

[image: see]

You need to handle that dependency, either by installing the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/) for your solution, or by directly downloading and providing the dll and its dependencies from the nuget site (not recommended).

Comment: I added it through Nuget Package manager in Visual Studio, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: I had to do it manually in order to work.